# How do I populate choices for combo box in powerapps?

Tags: combobox, microsoft-teams, dropdownbox, powerapps-formula, nested-table

Novice business user here: I am trying to build a schedule separated by date in Microsoft PowerApps for Teams. It would look something like the arrival/departure board at an airport.  I need my users to be able to change the status of an event on the schedule basically from "no go" to "go."

For my table, I created a table with columns showing the "no go" and "go" choices and set my default choices to "no go".

For my gallery, I created a nested gallery to separate the dates.

In the gallery,  I can populate the fields I created in my table with the "no go" default values, but when I click the dropdown arrow in the combo box, I either get irrelevant choices from a different text column, or I don't get any choices at all.

I have tried making different changes to the "text" and "items" properties. I just don't know how to make the choices I created in the table populate in the combo box dropdown.

Comment: If you have `Choice` column in SharePoint https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pkb9F.png and you want to populate those values in your PowerApps combo box https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHYVj.png, you need to set `Items` property to `Choices([@ListName].ColumnName)` and have to set `SearchFields` property to `["Value"]` and `IsSearchable` property to `true`. On searching: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VMis.png

Comment: Sorry, it has taken me a while to respond.

The table I am working with is in Dataverse instead of Sharepoint. The column is searchable.

Under Items, I implemented Choices([@ListName].ColumnName). That created a new table consisting of the correct column. So that works great!

However, the new table returns a message for each record of “This data type is unsupported for evaluation.” Does that mean the problem is with the column setting in the Dataverse? The Column is a choice column with only a local choice. Is making the choices global better? Let me know if you need clarification.

Comment: I couldn't get the exact issue you are facing now? You mean to say in your combo-box you are not able to get the values from the table which is created? The IntelliSense in the formula bar should tell you the correct property name to enter after the final dot.